# json file images won't load in ionic page

Tags: json, image, ionic-framework

I am trying to load some images from a file on a server to display on a list.  I get 404 not found error
after asking in forums, I get that the request URL is wrong, it looks inside the localhost not inside the json file.

https://filehost.net/db54d37849f75ddd

in the code I have a service which returns a response.  I use that response in a controller and to the view. I get other information but no images
if anybody has a solution that would be really great.

Answer (score 0):

please attach also some code, in this way it is easier to help you. About the problem, do have correct form of $http GET request? I mean does your get request points to correct address on server? something like this
`
// Simple GET request example:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

`

you can check more here [Angular $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/redamed/pen/mWLNvr) here's a link to the pen i made.the thing is  i get other informations from the json file.but not the images.

Comment: try using $stateparam dependency something like this 
http://codepen.io/keivan85/pen/OprjKd?editors=1010#0

Comment: i get the informations.i get the article using its id.what i don't get is the images.the only difference between your code and mine is enabling caching.

Comment: can you paste here the console log of success call back response

Comment: here it "4ba63eae07a5a6bbd7a5b858ba912479200.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8100/4ba63eae07a5a6bbd7a5b858ba912479200.jpg 404 (Not Found)" 404 not found as show in the screenshot.